# Mount ISO with write permissions?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, command-line, mount, iso

I'm trying to view and modify a [TinyCore](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/) ISO in Ubuntu. But it's getting mounted with read-only permissions. What am I getting wrong here?

```
sudo mount /tmp/Core-current.iso /tmp/foo/ -o rw
mount: /tmp/foo: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
```

Comment: AFAIK you cannot write to an ISO in that way

Comment: ISOs are read-only. To modify it, you basically need to re-create it with your modifications incorporated.

Answer (score 1):

ISO files are always mounted as read only. So copy files from the mounted ISO to another folder and then make changes you want. You can then use mkisofs to generate a new ISO from the modified folder.